# How to find a specific index of some values in list Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a function called **ModelsProduct**  in which I am generating all possible combinations of **"+/-"** and **"a,b,c,d,e"**. In the below code **#producemodelsOne**

modelsStepOne selects the all 8 combinations of **+/-**

modelsStepTwo selects the first value of list i-e **a**

modelsStepThree selects its first value of list i-e **('a','a')**

modelsStepFour selects its first value of list i-e **('d','d')**

modelsStepFive selects its first value of list i-e **('e','e')**

which makes a combination of [+,+,+,+,+,+,+,+,a,a,a,d,d,e,e] and iterates so on for all possible combinations.

Following is the Output when you print it.

```
print (modelsOne[0])
print (modelsOne[1])
```

('+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e')

('+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e')

**Question**
How to find a specific index value in all possible combinations e.g **What will be the index value of possible combination [+,-,+,+,+,+,-,-,a,a,b,c,c,e,c] ?**

**Here is the code for making all possible combinations**

```
def ModelsProduct(modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour,modelsFive):

modelsStepOne = list(product("+-",repeat = 8)) ## It gives total 12288 model combinations
modelsStepThree = [('a','a'),('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('a','e'),('b','b'),('b','c'),('b','d'),('b','e'),('c','c'),('c','d'),('c','e')]
modelsStepFour = [('d','d'),('d','e')]
modelsStepFive = [('e','e')]



#produce modelsOne
modelsStepTwo = [('a',),('b',)]
for one in modelsStepOne:
    for two in modelsStepTwo:
        for three in modelsStepThree:
            for four in modelsStepFour:
                for five in modelsStepFive:
                    modelsOne.append(one+two+three+four+five)


#produce modelsTwo
modelsStepTwo = [('a',),('b',)]
for one in modelsStepOne:
    for two in modelsStepTwo:
        for three in modelsStepThree:
            for four in modelsStepFour:
                for five in modelsStepFive:
                    modelsTwo.append(one+two+three+four+five)


#produce modelsThree
modelsStepTwo = [('a',),('b',)]
for one in modelsStepOne:
    for two in modelsStepTwo:
        for three in modelsStepThree:
            for four in modelsStepFour:
                for five in modelsStepFive:
                    modelsThree.append(one+two+three+four+five)

#ModelsFour
modelsStepTwo = [('a',),('d',)]
for one in modelsStepOne:
    for two in modelsStepTwo:
        for three in modelsStepThree:
            for four in modelsStepFour:
                for five in modelsStepFive:
                    modelsFour.append(one+two+three+four+five)

 #ModelsFive
modelsStepTwo = [('a',),('e',)]
for one in modelsStepOne:
    for two in modelsStepTwo:
        for three in modelsStepThree:
            for four in modelsStepFour:
                for five in modelsStepFive:
                    modelsFive.append(one+two+three+four+five)

 return modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour, modelsFive

modelsOne, modelsTwo,modelsThree, modelsFour,modelsFive = ModelsProduct(modelsOne, modelsTwo, modelsThree, modelsFour, modelsFive)
```

Comment: you can get the index of a element in a list by using `modelsOne.index()` so if you do `modelsOne.index(('+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e'))` you will get 0, is it your question?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to print the index value of any possible combination. The combination can be [+,-,+,-,+,-,-,-,a,a,b,c,d,d,e,] or [+,+,+,-,-,-,+,-,a,a,a,b,b,b,d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **index()** returns the index in list that obj appears. This method returns index of the found object otherwise raise an exception indicating that value does not find.

Example:

```
alist = [123, 'xyz', 'muhammad', 'abc'];
print ("Index for xyz : ", alist.index( 'xyz' ))
print ("Index for Muhammad : ", alist.index( 'muhammad' ) )

Index for xyz :  1
Index for Muhammad :  2
```

The problem discussed above in the question can be

```
 print("Index of ModelsOne :",modelsOne.index(('+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e')))
```

OutPut:

```
Index of ModelsOne :6144
```